# Android Marshmallow - Text Selection Menu Showing Awkwardly

Tags: android, contextmenu, android-6.0-marshmallow, menuitem, textselection

So I'm trying to add my own menu item to the Text Selection Context Menu on Android. However, it shows up really weird. Here is what it looks like:

[image: Text Selection Menu]

Here is my code:

```
etNote.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            menu.add(0, myItemId, 0, R.string.action_do);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            if (item.getItemId() == myItemId) {
                int start = etNote.getSelectionStart();
                int end = etNote.getSelectionEnd();
                String selection = etNote.getText().toString().substring(start, end).trim();
                if (!selection.isEmpty())
                    MyDialog.create(selection).show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),
                            TAG);
                else Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Text Selection is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

What do I do to make it look better?

Comment: check out this link if you want to add more option to text selection menu https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/selection.html#selection-text-selection

Comment: @krishankTripathi You referenced a design documentation. There is no code provided on your link.